# Where do I rescue my wife in the 3rd generation?

Tags: dragon-quest-v

I have the flying carpet and the flying castle. I have beaten the giant monster bothering Briscoletti at Mostroferrto tower. I got the Zenithian sword, helm, and shield. I think I have run out of plot threads to pull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

She is held and under a curse in the Zugzwag Temple that the main character was forced to build as a boy. I can't get there yet as I have to complete the Tower of the Dragon, on a continent not reachable before getting the floating castle.

Answer (score 1):

Drawing on the Wiki and its info on the [Story](https://dragonquest.fandom.com/wiki/Hero_(Dragon_Quest_V)/Story):

So, your wife's delivered the twins and you've had the coronation... It seems like you should climb the [Knightmare Towers](https://dragonquest.fandom.com/wiki/Knightmare_Towers) north of Gotha?

Comment: That is a handy story link. Thank you.